# In nature, (generally) when liquid molecules lies on a solid surface which model does it came close with?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-statics, surface-tension, wetting

In nature, (generally) when liquid molecules lies on a solid surface which model does it came close with? {Does water molecules lies on solid interface with air pocket or without air pocket?} Cassie-Baxter model state water molecules can easily roll across the solid surface thus it is preferred more compare to other two model. Shouldn't it be wrong to assume Cassie-Baxter model is better solely on that?

Why is contact angle for each individual methods (Young, Wenzel and Cassie-Baxter) assumed to be same even though contact surface area is different? At what regime do we consider to be super hydrophobic surface and hydrophobic surfaces for Young, Wenzel and Cassie-Baxter model?

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/615047/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic the question seems to be removed

Comment: @KarimChahine Yes, the post is 'hidden': only visible to those with sufficient rep.